# PHP array display image

Tags: php, html, arrays, image, output

How can I display a picture using php array so far using html didn't work its just displaying the string itself. Here is my code for it :

```
      $output = array(  
            'order_table'       =>  $order_table,
            'cart_item'         =>  '<img src="samples/cart.png">' .count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add quotation around   `img`tag and then display it using `echo` in php

```
 $output = array(  
            'order_table'       =>  $order_table,
            'cart_item'         =>  '<img src="samples/cart.png">' .count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]),
  );  

echo $output['cart_item']; //This will display the image
```